# Spark MLib's ALS not accepting Vector Assembler as an input to ItemCol

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a data frame having products features , so I create a vector Assembler for the same as below :

```
VectorAssembler vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(new String[] { "PRODUCT", "Feature1", "Feature2", "Feature3"}).setOutputCol("rawFeatures");
```

After this I create an instance of ALS and pass the param as below :

```
   ALS als = new ALS()
  .setUserCol("CUSTOMER_ID")
  .setItemCol("rawFeatures")
  .setRatingCol("UNIT_SOLD");
```

But I am getting and error as :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed: Column rawFeatures must be of type NumericType but
>   was actually of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7.

Now instead of "rawFeatures" if i pass just one column from data frame either of "PRODUCT", "Feature1", "Feature2", OR "Feature3" ; The code runs without throwing an exception, So I understand that it only wants to accept on numeric value but what if I have a more feature rich vectors. 
So the question is :

1. How do I pass a set of params instead of just one in ItemCol ? Can I use any specific transformer for that ?
2. What if I have a similar feature rich UserCol as well i.e having more than one characteristic, How do I handle them.

Comment: _How do I pass a set of params instead of just one in ItemCol_ - you don't. ALS expects an implicit (rating) or explicit (count-like) feedback, not features. _What if I have a similar feature rich UserCol_ - Same as above, you don't use ALS.